# Widget for Android in Nativescript with Angular 2

Tags: android, angular, widget, nativescript

It's possibile to make widget in Nativescript with Angular 2 for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Angular 2 in particular, but with JavaScript/TypeScript by calling to Android's API.

Here's a repo of a sample I wrote half a year ago. The project hasn't been updated since, so it may require an update of the platforms.

https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Android-Widgets